# array with doms turns into variable if only a single exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is pretty basic jquery I guess.

```
var counters = $(".move-counter");
for (var key in counters) {         
    console.log(counters[key].text()); 
}
```

The problem here is, that if I only a element with the class `move-counter` my variable counters wont be an array, but a single element, making the other `.text()` fail. What can I do to make sure it always turns into an array (in a way other than doing a simple `.length` or something of the like)?

Comment: Why are you doing `for..in` over a jQuery object?  Try using `.each()` (or `.map()`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over elements in a collection.

```
$(".move-counter").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: thx, this was pretty smart, trying to make my code pretty as I go along learning :)

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you actually need an array:

```
var counters = $(".move-counter");
counters.each(function(){
  var counter = $(this);
  console.log(counter.text());
})
```

Comment: ITYM `counter.text()`